# Is it possible to use Google Maps SDK and Places SDK for Android with two distinct API keys, one for each (or otherwise secure places lookup)?

Tags: android, google-maps

The [Android Maps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup) and the [Places SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start) both support API keys, but according to the docs they must be applied with only one key, given in the manifest with "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" (or the old maps variant). Due to the different pricing of Maps and Places, we need two distinct keys. Previously we have used Maps SDK for android with one key, and Places via https with another unsecured key. Its a client app where we don't control the IP, so it seems we cannot use Android, iOS, or IP restriction on the key in Google Console.

So Question 1

- Is it possible to use two distinct keys in the Android Play Services SDK's so we can use a Google Key which is restricted for Android?
- If not, is it otherwise possible to use places (autocomplete) lookup with a restricted key?

Comment: I couldn't understand do you use Places API for Android or Places API web service in your application?

Comment: I've edited it to make it more clear. Actually we currently use Maps SDK for Android and Places for Web in the app (plus geocode web-api),  but the problem is the Places for Web api key does not seem to support key-restriction to Android. The Places SDK for Android does support key restriction to Android, based on app certificate. We obviously cannot use key-restriction to IP (its arbitrary users), so we need some other security measure.

Comment: API key for web services supports only IP restriction. In this case you should create intermediate server that sends requests to Google and passes responses back to the client. With this approach you can restrict API key using IP address of the intermediate server.